# How to prevent future developers from abusing `switch` `default` clause?

Tags: swift

I’m writing a class to give the user the option of choosing which email app they want to use when sending email from our app.

I’m trying to do the following, but get a warning because I’ve specified a `default`. The `default` is there because I want to dissuade future developers from using the default instead of adding a case for any client they add.

```swift
private enum EmailApp {
    case appleMail
    case gmail
    case outlook

    typealias EmailAppConfiguration = (title: String, scheme: String?, path: String?)

    var configuration: EmailAppConfiguration {
        switch self {
        case .appleMail:
            return ("Apple Mail", nil, nil)
        case .gmail:
            return ("Gmail", "googlegmail://", "co")
        case .outlook:
            return ("MS Outlook", "ms-outlook://", "compose")
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unhandled email client. DO NOT use the default. Explicitly define the configuration when you add a new app.")
        } 
    }
}
```

I don’t like the warning. I could put a `guard` before the switch to do the precondition failure but it would be ugly too. What would you do?

Comment: Just simply remove the default from the switch statement. The advantage of using enums in Swift is just that - you don't *need* a default. Developers cannot code for it. (The other alternative is to add a .undefinedMailClient case to your enum and code for that instead of using default.

Comment: (1) Swift `switch` must be exhaustive, which you have already made so. No need to use `default`. (2) if you add a new `case` to the `enum` in the future, the compiler will give you a warning since the `switch` is no longer exhaustive. (3) you can't tell what the next developer will do to your code. Put in a comment as guidance, and leave it at that

Answer (score 0):

Throw an error or change your default? Don't provide functionality you wouldn't like people to use